# JDBC Assignment with no Java knowledge

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

You heard it right.

I am currently a Master's student at KU Leuven for Information Management programme and for our Database Management assignment, we have been asked to write an app that will make use of JDBC.

I have installed MySQL, MySQL Workbench and Eclipse without any problems and we are provided with the database and some kind of a template to work with.

The assignment is:

> The app asks a customer what s/he would like to do.
> If s/he would like to place a new order, s/he chooses option ‘1’. The program >asks the customer for her/his customer ID (only input existing customer ID’s >from the customer table). Next, the program outputs a list of products (id, >name, category), and asks the customer which product s/he wants to order. This >list needs to be ordered alphabetically by category and then by product name. >The program then outputs the restaurant that has the best rating for this >product (product name, restaurant name and rating). Additionally, it registers >the order in the correct database table.
>
> If a customer wants to see a list of product categories that have been ordered >at least 5 times, s/he chooses option ‘2’. A list of food category names >together with the number of orders is displayed, which is sorted by a >decreasing number of orders.
>
> If a customer wants to see the top 5 of most sold products, s/he chooses option >‘3’. The program shows a list of 5 products, together with the number of orders >(product ID, product name, number of orders), which is sorted by a dreasing >number of orders.
> This is repeated until the user enters a ‘0’. In that case, the program should >display the message ‘END OF SESSION’.

The sample code we are provided with is:

```
package connectionMySql;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class connectionMySql {

    /**
     * @author X X
     *
     */
    static {
        try {
            /* Type 4 Driver */
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not load MySql driver.");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String uname = null;
        String psswrd = null;
        Integer choice = 1;
        /* Location of the database */
        String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/orderdb";
        /* Sample query */
        String query = "SELECT * FROM restaurant";
        /* Reading log-in data (username and password) */
        try {
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter your username on MySql: ");
            uname = br1.readLine();
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter your password on MySql: ");
            psswrd = br2.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Failed to get uname/passwd");
            System.out.println(":" + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        /* Example of querying a database */
        try {
            /* Connect to MySql database */
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uname, psswrd);
            System.out.println("Connection established...");
            System.out.println();
            /* Create statement */
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            /* Execute the query */
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            /* Output */
            System.out.println("This is an example how you query a DBMS.");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(query);
            System.out.println("ID // First Name // Last Name");
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.print((" // "));
                System.out.print(rs.getString(2));
                System.out.print((" // "));
                System.out.print(rs.getString(3));
                System.out.print((" // "));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(4));
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        /* Example of choice options */
        while (choice != 0) {
            /*Ask for user's choice*/
            try {
                BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("This is an example of a choice menu.");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Please choose between the following options:");
                System.out.println(" (1) Add registration");
                System.out.println(" (2) Show popular sessions list");
                System.out.println(" (0) Quit");
                System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
                choice = Integer.parseInt(br1.readLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.err.println("Not a valid number");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (choice == 1) {
                /* TODO */
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                /* TODO */
            } else {
                /* TODO */
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("End of Session");
    }
}
```

I want to learn new things. That's why I am here however I do not come from an IT background and this much of assumption that I could do all this without problems is not realistic at all.

I do not have a hint if I am expected to do SQL queries (which I am a bit familiar with) or JDBC coding (which I do not know at all) to get what I want. Plus, I don't have any idea of how Java works, what classes are etc.

I am not looking for copy-pasteable shortcuts, I want guidance, something to start with. I am so frustrated right now.

Comment: You asked an honest question but it is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.  If you get stuck at a particular place in setting up JDBC then come back here with a more focused question.

Comment: I can't get stuck at someplace I could not "enter" to begin with. I am stuck at the door, to metaphorise, sir.

Comment: I would take a look at some of the learn to code sites out there.

Answer (score 2):

If you've never written Java before I'd say you're going to have a big problem.

JDBC and relational databases are not "Hello World".

You're working on a Masters degree.  You don't say what your undergraduate degree is, but let's assume that you can program.

The best place to start is the [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) from Oracle/Sun.

One comment: The code you posted is horrible.  The style is poor and it's hard to read.  I'd give the professor that handed out such a mess a failing grade.

Here's a recommendation: Big problems are easier to solve if you break them up into smaller ones.  Decomposition is a core skill in computer science.

I'd recommend that you not put everything in a main method.  Decompose discrete operations into separate methods that you can code and test independently.

It's never too early to learn about [JUnit](http://www.junit.org).  You will find this far less painful if you write a method, test it, and move onto the next.

Relational databases all do the same thing: CRUD operations (Create/Read/Update/Delete).  You can start with a generic interface:

```
package persistence;

public interface DataAccess<K, V> {
    List<V> findAll();
    V find(K key);
    K save(V value);
    void update(K key, V value);
    void delete(K key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth look.

I am a Business Administration graduate and no coding skill prior to this MSc. That was why I was very very frustrated.

After writing to you, some lad with IT background offered to help and we were done with my assignment in 2 hours.

Thank you very much for your input anyway.

Comment: You're being done a disservice.  It'd be a shame to raise expectations with a Masters degree in computer science and not have any understanding of what you're doing.  Do not be fooled - you may have been "done" with this assignment in 2 hours, but you didn't do it.  You have light years to go towards becoming a competent programmer.  Don't settle for someone else doing your work for you.  The lad who helped you knows a little, but you don't.  Buckle down and learn how to do things properly.

Comment: I do not know how you thought that I regarded myself a "competent" coder or that I take full credit for that assignment.

Comment: It was clear that you did not consider yourself a competent programmer.  The tell tale bit was "WE were done with my assignment in 2 hours".    I'm guessing that you won't tell your professor about the lad's help.  He'll have no idea that you still don't know anything about Java, JDBC, or programming.  That's what I call intellectual dishonesty.

Comment: The harm for you is that you'll graduate with an MS in computer science.  If you get a job, your employers will have some expectation that you understand computer science and can actually program.  On that day it won't matter what grade you got on this assignment.  It'll be yoda-like: Do, or do not.  Better for you to suffer and learn now.

Comment: We will have an oral exam on the assignment if that will make you feel better over it.

Comment: Of course I will not be telling them because I am considered knowledgable enough to program in Java while knowing Java is not a prerequisite for this degree nor it is an obligatory course. So if anyone is at fault, they share it.

In other news, I am here to learn something new and coding is a part of it. The moment I'll find enough time from my wife and my 1.5 year old daughter I will. I already am happy with what they have taught me like BPRM, Declare model and SQL.

This is MSc in Inf. Mngmnt, btw.

Comment: I am not allowed to edit so, I have to correct it as BPMN.